# Activation of Bootcamped Windows 7 in VMWare Fusion, is it legal?

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, vmware-fusion, license, legal

I have bought a boxed version of Windows 7 Home Premium (not OEM). I want to install this on new iMac via bootcamp but I also want to use this Bootcamped partition via VMWare Fusion.

VMWare fusion has article about [activating bootcamped windows installation](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003426).

Does this work setup work for you? Is it ok according to license?

Comment: I'm interested in experience with running such setup (windows activated under bootcamp and also vmware fusion), but also if this is ok wrt to licensing. Even though SU is not legal advice server, I believe that some people might have investigated this and have opinion.

Comment: SU cannot provide you with legal advice.  Legal queestions are off-topic, very localized(laws are different depending on where you are) and should be left to the lawyers.   Please don't ask legal questions.  See the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)

Comment: @heavyd: I do understand your concerns, and legal advice may indeed  differ based on country. I do also understand that lawyers do not read this site. FAQ doesn't mention questions like this explicitly, I've only found this on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19886/not-the-place-for-legal-questions, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17509/how-to-handle-questions-that-may-have-legal-concerns

Comment: legal questions really are too localized for this site.   if you want to refocus the question on the technical aspects, edit your question and flag for moderator attention to be considered for reopening.  note it's likely there are already technical questions about this kind of setup, so search around first.  in fact, this question in its original form is basically a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/94237/legal-to-install-an-oem-license-of-windows-7-in-vmware-fusion

Comment: This setup works fine.  I use it at home and at work (separate win7 installs).  Setup bootcamp and activate windows.  Then setup parallels / vm - you will have to reactivate.  MS allows for this.  The nice part of this setup is that you can access the same windows software from Mac or natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mention of "virtual" in the EULA is this section:

> **d. Use with Virtualization Technologies.** Instead of using the software directly on the licensed computer, you may install and use the software within only one virtual (or otherwise emulated) hardware system on the licensed computer. When used in a virtualized environment, content protected by digital rights management technology, BitLocker or any full volume disk drive encryption technology may not be as secure as protected content not in a virtualized environment. You should comply with all domestic and international laws that apply to such protected content.

To me this reads that as long as you are only running one instance of the virtual machine (don't start VMware Fusion twice or something like that) you can switch between your license to use the software in VMware Fusion (as identified by the EULA above) and your license to use the software on a physical machine as often as you want (since it is the same licensed copy you paid for).

If you get stuck, you can send an email to licensing@microsoft.com and see what they say. Note that when I have contacted their licensing support in the past they were pretty clueless about virtualisation except to say that they highly recommend you use Hyper-V over VMware.

Comment: this is assuming, of course, that that's the same license the OP read.  :)

Comment: It's the English Windows 7 Home Premium EULA. As far as I can tell this EULA is not localised to any particular English-speaking country.